# Point in Polygon (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, raycasting

I have a google maps api v3, which uses "The Di Lab"'s plugin for polygon drawing:

http://www.the-di-lab.com/?p=219

And then uses tparkins plugin for raycasting.

https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

However, I need to access the polygon object from the polygon plugin. The section in the polygon plugin that actually plots the Polygon on the map is:

```
this.polygonObj= new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: this.coords,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map:this.map
});
```

And I would create the map with:

`var creator = new PolygonCreator(map);`

I then  have to do the point in polygon via calling:

`var isWithinPolygon = polygonObj.containsLatLng("52,0");`

So for example:

```
var coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(40,90);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon([], "#000000", 1, 1, "#336699", 0.3);
var isWithinPolygon = polygon.containsLatLng(coordinate);
```

Basically all I need is the polygon object from the first script. The two javascript files are below:

http://80.229.168.62/guild_service/server/js/polygon.min.js

http://80.229.168.62/guild_service/server/js/latlngcontains.js

The page running the scripts is:

http://80.229.168.62/guild_service/server/map_view.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the Polygon via the `creator.pen.drawPloygon()` (no that's not a typo on my part--the function really is spelled that way in polygon.min.js), then you should be able to retrieve it from `creator.pen.polygon.getPolygonObj()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much, however if I do this, I get the following error: `a.lat is not a function` - see: http://80.229.168.62/guild_service/server/map_view.php?location=Manchester&radius=1609.344# -

Comment: Be sure to pass the correct parameters to `drawPloygon()`!  It looks like you've taken down the files from the links in your question, but I seem to recall it took four parameters.  Look at the source code to see what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please note the polygon creator URL has been moved to 
http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/google-map-api-v3-polygon-shape-creator

:)

Regards
XD
www.the-di-lab.com